# histogram with opaque bars

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

If I make a histogram using `plotly.express`, then the colors cover each other:

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="sex", marginal="rug",
                   hover_data=df.columns)
fig.show()
```

[image]

However, if I use `ff.create_distplot`, then the colors are more transparent:

```py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

# Add histogram data
x1 = np.random.randn(200) - 2
x2 = np.random.randn(200)
x3 = np.random.randn(200) + 2
x4 = np.random.randn(200) + 4

# Group data together
hist_data = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 4']

# Create distplot with custom bin_size
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=.2)
fig.show()
```

[image]

This shows transparent colors, which is much nicer.

Is there a way to get the colors to appear like that in `px.histogram`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, just use `barmode='overlay'`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the first fig, it's beter not using transparent colors as the result shown is the sum of tip.
Of course, depending on how you want to use this tool and what you want to represent, transparent colors might be usefulls.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30809147)